# Ivy/sbt bug for maven dependency that has variables, is there a fix yet?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, ivy

You might have a setup like me, a maven2 build but not sure if that makes a difference:

```
parent/pom.xml
parent/project/pom.xml <-depends on spring.version in parent
```

Then your sbt build has:

```
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  :: org.springframework#spring-core;${spring.version}: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.springframework#spring-core;${spring.version}: not found
```

At first, googling for hours, I found the fix:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/3OkYLXzHwG4

Then later when I switched the way I blessed builds, I had to search across my browser history to find it again!

Is there a superior method to keep others from this rabbit hole?

Edit: the earlier thread mentioned:

```
mvn help:effective-pom -P scala2.9.2 -Doutput=tmp.pom
mvn -f tmp.pom clean source:jar scala:doc-jar package deploy
```

I was able to get away with:

```
mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=effective.pom && mvn -f effective.pom source:jar deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sbt 1.3.13, I was able to run `update` with the following project without an error:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.13.2"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "parentpom",
    libraryDependencies += "com.googlecode.mapperdao" % "mapperdao" % "1.0.0.rc15-2.9.2"
  )
```

I guess Coursier has better handling of POM files.